# Цикл с read выполняется только один раз

Tags: bash, sh

Помогите составить скрипт, который будет брать ip из файла и подставлять их в команду connect в bash, надо подключаться к устройствам из списка ip, нашел только пример с использованием while, но мозг домохозяйки не позволяет превратить его в полноценный скрипт :) Он выполняется 1 раз и все, не пойму как указать ему чтобы брал следующий ip из списка и повторял все заново, и по возможности как нибудь реагировал на ошибки.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=server.txt
while read line; 
do

./adb connect "$line";
./adb pm uninstall com.guano.app;
./adb disconnect;

done < $file
```

Comment: А можно глянуть на файл с ip? Просто на самом деле должен проходить до конца файла. (кстати точки с запятой совершенно лишние здесь, они нужны если вы в одну строку несколько команд записываете)

Comment: @Fisherman список ip, обычный текстовый файл, на каждой строке по одному ip и все, больше ничего нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

очевидно, что выполняемые внутри цикла программы выбирают все данные из *stdin*, и при второй итерации команде `read` уже ничего не остаётся.

чтобы команде *read* было что читать, надо «подсунуть» этим программам что-нибудь другое в качестве *stdin*. обычно в таких случаях используют специальный пустой файл `/dev/null`.

вариант 1. передаём его в качестве *stdin* каждой программе:

```
./adb ... < /dev/null
```

вариант 2. объединяем все программы в блок с помощью скобок `{}` и передаём *stdin* для всего блока:

```
{
  ./adb ...
  ./adb ...
} < /dev/null
```

Comment: спасибо, вариант со скобками подошёл! :) Единственное что, последняя строка с ip из списка не обрабатывается если после неё не вставить пустую строку, но это не проблема.